# Not able to add Cookies for IE8 browser (Java, Selenium Grid, WebDriver 2.41.0)

Tags: java, cookies, internet-explorer-8, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I create remote webdriver as:

```
URL hubUrl =  new URL("http://172.30.234.216:4444/wd/hub");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubUrl, capabilities);
```

In each test scenario I have a step which sets some value into Browser cookies.

```
//....
webDriver.navigate().to("192.168.0.3:8060");
webDriver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("parameter_name", "parameter_value", "127.0.0.1", "/", null));
//....
```

As far as I know, we can't set the cookies until some page be loaded.
That's why I opened an empty page before setting cookies.

This approach works for Chrome and FireFox, but doesn't for IE8 (I didn't try another versions of IE).
I have the next error:

```
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'windows_slave', ip: '192.168.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: cbc78331-89f7-43ee-b414-cb7586655592
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:33505/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
Command duration or timeout: 50 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'my-pc', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.8.0-35-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: 89a27569-af4f-4bb7-b346-5b848ce2c22d
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, webdriver.remote.sessionid=89a27569-af4f-4bb7-b346-5b848ce2c22d, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:33505/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions.addCookie(RemoteWebDriver.java:669)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParameterisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:533)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to add cookie to page (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 21 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'windows_slave', ip: '192.168.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: cbc78331-89f7-43ee-b414-cb7586655592
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:33505/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'my-pc', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.8.0-35-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions.addCookie(RemoteWebDriver.java:669)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringOptions.addCookie(EventFiringWebDriver.java:503)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.AddCookie.call(AddCookie.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.AddCookie.call(AddCookie.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I use:

- Selenium WebDriver: 2.41.0
- IEDriverServer: 2.41.0
- Internet Explorer: 8

Regards, Sergii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the workaround: set the cookie value via JavaScript

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("document.cookie='cookieName=value'");
```

Comment: I tried to set a cookie like this prior to opening a website and got the following exception.  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: <unknown>: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.89)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for this in selenium project - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1227